# Camersource on huawei devices

Tags: android

I am using a Camerasource in my mobile application and it works fine on all devices except for Huawei devices it gets a black window although I put the camera permission check but it is not even displaying it, and even when I try to open the permission to the camera manually from the device itself the problem is not solved. 
Could you please tell me what is the problem?

***EDIT***

these are the camera permission check:

```
public void askForContactPermission() throws IOException {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ResultActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ResultActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ResultActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Contacts access needed");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setMessage("please confirm Contacts access");//TODO put real question
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        requestPermissions(
                                new String[]
                                        {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}
                                , RequestCameraPermissionID);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();




            } else {



                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ResultActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        RequestCameraPermissionID);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
        }
    } else {
        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ResultActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                        return;
                    }else {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No permission for camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ResultActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);

            }
            return;
        }


    }
}
```

and this is the camerasource usage in the code:

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();


        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {


            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                try {
                    askForContactPermission();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }


            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
```

and the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: post your code!

Comment: Sorry for being late, I have edited the post with the code